# Azure DevOps Various Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

total noob here and I hope this isn’t a sill question. I’m supposed to be helping design a strategy for infra deployments using DevOps, I’m trying to work out the best way to do the organisation, as DevOps will only be used for infra build, I was thinking one organisation and one project, but we will have about 34 different build pipelines to configure, am I better off having 34 projects or how do I isolate the repos and multiple pipelines?

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Microsoft's guidance is to use as few Projects as possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/agile-culture?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops#scale-with-teams-and-not-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not needed to create 34 projects in Azure DevOps, you could create multiple repos in one team project:

[image]

Then you could create pipeline for each repo.

Comment: can you have multiple pipelines under one project/repo?

Comment: Yes, you can. You could use path filters in your trigger to include or exclude paths: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths